# BeautifulSoup - Scraping multiple pages but previous page data not being stored in the list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, append

BeautifulSoup - Scraping multiple pages but previous page data not being stored in the list.

I'm a beginner and have been scratching my head on this for some time. I'm trying to scrape 5 pages and store all data in one data frame and save it as cvs. Every time I run my code, I get 24 records just from the last page. Looks like my list is not holding the data from previous pages. What am I screwing up? Thanks!

```
#importing libraries 

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

#send request
#Getting the first 5 pages
for x in range(0,6):
    url = 'https://apps.shopify.com/browse/all?page='
    page = requests.get(url+str(x))
#parse the html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#read app name and add it to the app_name list
    app_name = []
    app_name_elm = soup.find_all(class_='ui-app-card__name')
    for item in app_name_elm:
        app_name.append(item.text)
#read app rating and add it to the app_rating list
    app_rating = []
    app_rating_elm = soup.find_all(class_='ui-star-rating__rating')
    for item in app_rating_elm:
        app_rating.append(item.text)
#read app review count and add it to the app_reviews list
    app_reviews = []
    app_reviews_elm = soup.find_all(class_='ui-review-count-summary')
    for item in app_reviews_elm:
        app_reviews.append(item.text)
#read app link and add it to the app_link list
    app_link = []
    app_link_elm = soup.find_all(class_='grid__item grid__item--tablet-up-half grid-item--app-card-listing')
    for item in app_link_elm:
        app_link.append(item.find('a').get('href'))
#creating a dataframe
    final_list = []
    for name, rating, review, link in zip(app_name,app_rating,app_reviews,app_link):
        final_list.append({'Application_Name':name,'Rating':rating,'Number_Of_Reviews':review,'Link':link})
    df = pd.DataFrame(final_list)

print(df)
#df.to_csv('part1_scrape.csv')
```

Comment: Dataframe is initialising repeatedly inside loop hence holding only the last entry.

Comment: hi there neohex - many thanks for this great thread it is very helpful since i am learing alot through it. Do you add the changes to the code!? That would be fantastic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating these variables `app_name = []`, `app_rating = []` , `app_reviews = []` etc inside the `loop` . Move them outside the loop.

And move the last part , that is , `df = pd.DataFrame(final_list)` outside the loop.

Comment: Won't help if dataframe is created inside the loop.

Comment: ya he should also move the `df` line outside

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I moved all my variables and the dataframe outside of the loop and works like a charm now.

Comment: hi there - good day der sowjana hello der Shweta - manythnks for this great thread. i really like this great example for the usage of pandas. This thread is a avaluable asset. Many thanks for all you did!

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your variable `df` everytime in you loop. What you can do is save all the results in a list:

```
results = [] #create an empty list outside the loop
for x in range(0,6):
    url = 'https://apps.shopify.com/browse/all?page='
    page = requests.get(url+str(x))
#parse the html
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#read app name and add it to the app_name list
    app_name = []
    app_name_elm = soup.find_all(class_='ui-app-card__name')
    for item in app_name_elm:
        app_name.append(item.text)
#read app rating and add it to the app_rating list
    app_rating = []
    app_rating_elm = soup.find_all(class_='ui-star-rating__rating')
    for item in app_rating_elm:
        app_rating.append(item.text)
#read app review count and add it to the app_reviews list
    app_reviews = []
    app_reviews_elm = soup.find_all(class_='ui-review-count-summary')
    for item in app_reviews_elm:
        app_reviews.append(item.text)
#read app link and add it to the app_link list
    app_link = []
    app_link_elm = soup.find_all(class_='grid__item grid__item--tablet-up-half grid-item--app-card-listing')
    for item in app_link_elm:
        app_link.append(item.find('a').get('href'))
#creating a dataframe
    final_list = []
    for name, rating, review, link in zip(app_name,app_rating,app_reviews,app_link):
        final_list.append({'Application_Name':name,'Rating':rating,'Number_Of_Reviews':review,'Link':link})
    df = pd.DataFrame(final_list)
    results.append(df) #Append result to the list

print(results)
```